# Google Play: REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core purpose

Tags: android, google-play

Google Play again rejected my app because I'm apparently using REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission in my app. I never had this permission ever, I never had this issue before.

I checked merged manifest to find that kind of permission. There is none.

I've added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

tag into my AndroidManifest.xml to be certain that my App is not using this kind of permission EVER. Even Merged Manifest is not containing that permission and at the bottom of the Merged Manifest there is Android Studio warning that I'm removing something that is not even present in my app:

```
Warning uses-permission#android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:25 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present MyApp.app main manifest (this file), line 24
```

So either I'm missing something or their app validation is broken and Google is false-flagging my app validation for some unknown reason.

There has to be some serious issues with their validation methods past 2 weeks because amount of issues I've got with my app is unacceptable. App has same permissions and using same libraries and their version for past 2 years and I never had any issues like this before.

And I'm not sure what else I can do to get my app validated and accepted again.

Comment: Are you perhaps using a library that is now using that permission after being updated or something?

Comment: I dont think so. Merged Manifest should contain all permission requested by other libraries. I'm using just 2 libraries in my app which are 3rd party. Then I have usually google analytics, crashlytics and play services

Comment: share your manifest.xml here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have previous builds with `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission in the `Open`, `Closed`, or `Internal` testing you need to upload a new build without `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission to `Internal testing` and then promote it to production.

If this solution does not work for you check the permissions used in your app at `Google Play console`. If `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` is not shown there you must contact them and explain your problem and request again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a case where a really old build was in a closed test track and was requesting `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission. This was preventing me to create a new release even if my new release was not requesting the `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission anymore.

Google Play Developer Support explain me in a support ticket that **I HAD to fill the permission declaration form to be able to create the new releases**... It worked but it still looks like a bug to me :-)

Here is the exchange with google, I think it might help somebody someday.

First my request

> 2 old releases from years ago are blocking new releases process because
> they used to request "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" permission. I want to
> delete them (release xxxx & xxxx) but it's not possible (even if
> they are in suspended tracks)
>
> 1. Open "Wathever track name you gave it" closed track
> 2. Hit "create a release" button
> 3. Add a recent bundle (which does not require
>    REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) OR do not add any bundle in "App bundles"
>    section
> 4. verify previous app bundle (the faulty one) is in "not
>    included" section
> 5. fill release name
>    "No-release-i-want-to-delete-you-please"
> 6. Hit next => Error "Your
>    release has errors", it looks like it test the not included package
>    for permissions, this make no sense.Thanks for fixing that

And their answer

> I understand you'd like to deactivate a non-compliant version code 4.0.10 and 4.8.2 in the internal testing track. You can only roll out releases one track at a time, so other tracks still technically declare the permission declaration. Therefore, you will need to fill the declaration to unblock yourself, since the declaration considers all the release tracks.
>
> Please fill in the permission declaration form with whatever information you have in order to submit the update, even if the update doesn't use the said permission. You should specify that you want to declare that the new update is not using the said permissions and you are filling the form just for submitting the update. Please follow the below steps:
>
> 1. Go to your Play Console.
> 2. Select the app.
> 3. Go to the track where the non-compliant version code is active.
>
> You can confirm where the non-compliant version code is active by going to:
>
> - Release > Releases overview > Add filter > Version code > Search > Apply
> - Release > App bundle explorer > Search by version code or name > View app version (right arrow symbol)
>
> 4. Near the top right of the page, click Create new release. (You may need to click Manage track first)
>
>    If the release with the violating version code is in a draft state, discard the release.
> 5. Under the new release page, you can:
>
> Upload a new, compliant version code and roll out new release to 100% to completely deactivate the non-compliant version.
>
> Roll out a blank release (i.e., a release with all version codes under the "Deactivated app bundles" section and no version codes under the "New app bundles" or "Retained app bundles" sections) and roll it out to 100%.
>
> 6. Select Save.
> 7. When you've finished preparing your release, select Review release.
>
> If the non-compliant version code is released to multiple tracks,
> repeat steps 3-8 in each track.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked in Feb 2023.

I wanted to remove an APK from the Internal Test Track due to an older app having the `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission set. Even though later versions of the app did not include this, it blocked production releases.

I needed to update the test track:

- Create new release on test track with a newer APK
- IF you are blocked by an old APK mention this permission is no longer set in later versions and update the app permissions form
- Submit and roll out test track

Reply from Google r.e. permissions blocking releases:

> Google Play restricts the use of high risk or sensitive permissions,
> including the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission, which allows an
> application to request installing packages.
>
> If your current release doesn't have this permission, you are still
> required to submit this form because our system detected that your app
> was using this permission in your existing release. You can just fill
> out the form and inform the review team that you do not have any
> permissions in your current release.
>
> Also, to deactivate the current APK, you need to release a new
> compliant app bundle or APK on the same track where the non-compliant
> version is located in order for the non-compliant APK to be
> deactivated. The new release will then supersede or overwrite the
> non-compliant APK on your app. In this case, please update your
> Sensitive permissions and APIs in your App Content section. After
> that, please try to release your new versions to their specific track.

Comment: I imagine Google support flooded by this same request ever and ever, until somebody figures out they should do something about it on THEIR side because it makes no sense :-)